# Kibana service appearing pending

Tags: kubernetes, elastic-stack

I'm running an ELK stack on a Kubernetes cluster but the Kibana service is showing as pending. What does it means and how can we make running?

kubectl get svc -n kube-system | grep kibana

kibana-logging  LoadBalancer   10.0.34.12       5601:31840/TCP       5d

Answer (score 2):

It means that it cannot create the LoadBalancer to expose your service. This varies depending on what cloud provider you are using. For example, AWS, GCE, Azure, OpenStack, etc.

The main config on the `kube-apiserver`, `kube-controller-manager` and your `kubelet` is to provide the `--cloud-provider` option. For example for AWS it would be `--cloud-provicer=aws`.  If your cloud provider supported you might want to consider exposing the service as [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)